# 3d points to rotation matrix of orientation

Tags: math, matrix, 3d, rotation, point

I have 2 3d points:
point1 = (x1, y1, z1).
point2 = (x2, y2, z2).

I want to calculate the rotation matrix R of orientation of the vector   between this two points.
The translation of this vector is:
A = (x1-x2, y1-y2, z1-z2).

How I can calculate this? (In easy and efficient calculation/implement).

c++ code is optional.
I am using Egan and GTSAM libraries.

Comment: http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/algebra/vectors/angleBetween/

Comment: I need 3 Euler or rotation matrix. one angle is not enough for me.